# VB.Net - select whole line in a multicolumn ListView and not only first item

Tags: vb.net, listview, appearance, multiple-columns

I have a ListView in VB.Net.
I want to use it to display a table of data.
However **I want to be able to click on a row and select it**.
The component allows me to select a row only by clicking on the first item of each row.

- Can I change that?
- Is there a better component to display tables? (I've already tried the DataGridView. I don't like it's appearance)

Comment: Have you tried setting ListView's property "FullRowSelect" to true?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should simply be a matter of setting `FullRowSelect` on the control to be `True`.

Answer (score 3):

Change the FullRowSelect property to True.